# Searching array of objects using jquery grep with wildcards

Tags: jquery, arrays, search, object, grep

I'm searching an array of objects using jquery grep and would like to include wildcards in the search. For example, I have an array as follows:

```
courses = [
{code: 'ENCH3TH', otherFields: otherStuff},
{code: 'ENCH3THHS1', otherFields: otherStuff},
{code: 'ENCH3TH2', otherFields: otherStuff},
{code: 'ENCH4RT', otherFields: otherStuff},
{code: 'ENCH4MT', otherFields: otherStuff}]
```

I'd like to get all the courses with the ENCH3TH prefix. I have attempted

```
var resultSet = $.grep(courses, function(e){ return e.code == 'ENCH3TH/'; });
```

..to no avail (note the use of the '/' after 'ENCH3TH' as the wildcard).

Comment: In what language is `/` a wildcard?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [String.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) here, `=` will not work with wild chars

```
var resultSet = $.grep(courses, function (e) {
    return e.code.indexOf('ENCH3TH') == 0;
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/Dx9Ur/)

Or use regex

```
var regex = /^ENCH3TH/
var resultSet = $.grep(courses, function (e) {
    return regex.test(e.code);
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/C32NF/)