# Find all elements of particular object from object array using jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, associative-array

```
courses = [{
  code: 'English',
  otherFields: '1',
  list: [{id:'1'},{name:'eng'}]
}, {
  code: 'Spanish',
  otherFields: '2',
  list: [{id:'2'},{name:'spa'}]
}, {
  code: 'German',
  otherFields: '3',
  list: [{id:'3'},{name:'ger'}]
}]

 var resultSet = $.grep(courses.list, function (e) {
 return e.code.indexOf('German') == 0;
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(resultSet));
```

What I want is: based on 'name' parameter I want to get everything in that particular object. Example: when I pass name=spa I should get ' id=2, name=spa'. Using the above code I get the result as undefined.

I check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18757848/searching-array-of-objects-using-jquery-grep-with-wildcards) but it didn't help much. Please help.

**EDIT**

Sorry friends but I'm really confused. Below is the code while I can see in console (Its coming from server so I don't know how it is actually structured).

```
result : {Object}
 course : {Object}
  name : English
  list : {Object}
   1 : {Object}
     attr1 : value1
     attr2 : value2
   3 : {Object}
     attr1 : value1
     attr2 : value2
  other : value-other
  id : 1
 course : {Object}
  name : Spanish
  list : {Object}
   1 : {Object}
     attr1 : value1
     attr2 : value2
   3 : {Object}
     attr1 : value1
     attr2 : value2
  other : value-other
  id : 2
```

When I'm using `result.course.id` I'm getting `1`. What I want is to get the entire thing inside `course` based on particular `name` (Spanish or English). I hop I made myself clear now.

Sorry for the inconvenience that you'd to face before. Please help.

Comment: What does _First all elements_ mean? Did you mean _Find all elements_?

Comment: FWIW, `[{id:'2'},{name:'spa'}]` is a rather unusual data structure.

Comment: Why an array of objects with different keys, instead of a single object with all those keys?

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you check it now please

Answer (score 0):

You were on the right track with `jQuery.grep()` but did not use it correctly.

What you can do is:

```
$.grep(courses, function(e) { return e.list[1].name == 'spa'; })
```

Or more generally:

```
function find(name) {
    return $.grep(courses, function(e) { return e.list[1].name == name; });
}
```

And it will return all the elements of the `courses` array that match the given `name`.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a function for you. You can do it simply by:-

```
function FindCourse(code) {
        for (var i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {

            if (courses[i].list[1].name === code) {
                alert(courses[i].code);
                alert(courses[i].otherFields);
                alert(courses[i].list[0].id);
                alert(courses[i].list[1].name);
            }
        }
    }
```

See fiddle-http://jsfiddle.net/rMECV/4/

Comment: I have updated the question. Can you check it now please