# Find all elements of specific object from object array

Tags: jquery, object, associative-array

I had posted the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22575092/find-all-elements-of-particular-object-from-object-array-using-jquery-or-javascr) but did not get any answer that worked for me (may be I wasn't clear enough with my question). SO I'm posting it here again with clearly what I want.

Below is the code while I can see in console (Its coming from server so I don't know how it is actually structured).

```
result : {Object}
 course : {Object}
  name : English
  list : {Object}
   1 : {Object}
     attr1 : value1
     attr2 : value2
   3 : {Object}
     attr1 : value1
     attr2 : value2
  other : value-other
  id : 1
 course : {Object}
  name : Spanish
  list : {Object}
   1 : {Object}
     attr1 : value1
     attr2 : value2
   3 : {Object}
     attr1 : value1
     attr2 : value2
  other : value-other
  id : 2
```

Based on this I suppose the structure would be:

```
results = {
  other: 'something',
  id: '1',
  courses: {list:{...},name:'English'}
  }, {
  other: 'again-something',
  id: '2',
  courses: {list:{...},name:'Spanish'}
  }, {
  other: 'again-something',
  id: '3',
  courses: {list:{...},name:'German'}
};
```

What I want is: Get all the elements of `result.course` where `result.course.name = 'Spanish'`

I tried the below code but it return an empty array:

```
var test = $.grep(result, function(e) { return e.courses.name == 'Spanish'; });
console.log(JSON.stringify(test));
```

I guess the problem is that `result` itself is an object and not an array. If it is `result = [{...}];` then somehow the code works.

Can anyone please tell me how to work this out when `result` is itself an `object`.

Thanks.

Comment: Which console are you looking at? You should add screenshot or JSBin example. Your above data is confusing because it is not clear if there is an array inside result that holds all courses. If you are using Chrome then you should be able to expand levels and add screenshot of what you see.

Comment: @ShitalShah I'm getting these as result of 'console.log()' which is also being done from server side (some kind of rpc call). Unfortunately I cannot create fiddle. No there is no array in `result` and `result` itself is an object.

Comment: well...your javascript-object "results" is definitly wrong structured..if you can give the right json-object you'll get help for sure

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the exact object hierarchy you have in your scenario, but:

I created an array of objects as below:

```
var o = [{
  result: {
    course: { 
       name: "English",
       list: [{ attr1: "v1", attr2: "v2" }, { attr1: "v5", attr2: "v6" }],
       other: "value-other",
       id: "1"
    }
  }
},
{
  result: {
    course: { 
       name: "Spanish",
       list: [{ attr1: "v1", attr2: "v2" }, { attr1: "v5", attr2: "v6" }],
       other: "value-other",
       id: "1"
    }
  }
},
{
  result: {
    course: { 
       name: "French",
       list: [{ attr1: "v1", attr2: "v2" }, { attr1: "v5", attr2: "v6" }],
       other: "value-other",
       id: "1"
    }
  }
}]
```

Executing `var test = $.grep(o, function(e) { return e.result.course.name == "Spanish"; } );` returns the object which course name is Spanish (2nd element from my array).

Grep expects an array - o is my array of objects with structure of result -> course -> name, list, other, id.

Grep then loops over each element of the array - each element of the array is an object with a single property - "result" - which contents, in turn, is a "course" object, which properties are finally name, list, other and id.

That's why within grep I access e.result.course.name.

Hope this sheds some light.